# Access Kafka in Remote Host by IP Address running with Docker-Compose and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I have this docker-compose.yml in which I run **Zookeeper**, **Kafka**, **Kafka Connect**, and **KafDrop**, the thing is, when I run locally I can connect from my **Spring Boot** application to consume some topic messages.

What I need is to run the same configuration on a Linux machine and be able to connect from the Spring Boot application the same way.

When run it remotely on the Linux machine everything seems to be running Ok, but when I try to connect from the Spring Boot application I receive some erros showing that somethin is wrong in the connection.

I will try to explain step by step and see if someone can give a "light" on that:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 
         INTERNAL://kafka:29092,
         EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 
         INTERNAL://kafka:29092,
         EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 
         INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,
         EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 12
    
  connect:
    image: cdc:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-1
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-1-config
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-1-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-1-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_OFFSET.STORAGE.REPLICATION.FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_CONFIG.STORAGE.REPLICATION.FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET.STORAGE.PARTITIONS: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS.STORAGE.REPLICATION.FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS.STORAGE.PARTITIONS: 1
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 19000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
      
networks: 
  broker-kafka:
    driver: bridge
```

What I need is to expose to my network this IP machine to be accessed by my Spring Boot application.
Let´s suppose this Linux machine has the IP 10.12.54.99.
How can I make it Kafka be accessible by: 10.12.54.99:9090 ?

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=10.12.54.99:9092

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-commit-interval=100
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=10
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=connect-sql-server
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual-immediate
spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=3000
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=3

spring.kafka.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

This is a only consumer-specif application (no producers are used here).

When I run the application:

```
2020-12-07 10:59:40.361  WARN 58716 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-sql-server-1, groupId=connect-sql-server] Connection to node -1 (/10.12.54.99:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-12-07 10:59:40.362  WARN 58716 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-sql-server-1, groupId=connect-sql-server] Bootstrap broker 10.12.54.99:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

All the firewall ports are enabled in the Linux firewall machie.

Any enlightenment would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `EXTERNAL://localhost:9092` The `ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` need to be set to the actual connection that will be used by the remote client to connect to the broker instance (or you need to set up a tunnel between the linux host and the localhost port(s)).

Comment: @GaryRussell I am not sure if I got it, what do you mean by the "set to the actual connection"? But thanks for helping!

Comment: I mean you are advertising 2 listeners, one on `kafka` and one on `localhost`. The Kafka clients use this to actually connect to the brokers after initial handshaking. i.e. you would need `EXTERNAL://10.12.54.99:9090` - but I realize that would tie your docker yaml to the host; I don't know docker well enough to advise if there's a better way. Another solution would be an SSH tunnel that forwards `10.12.54.99:9090` to `localhost:9092` on the host, but I would hope there's a better way with docker, somehow.

Comment: Gary is correct, unfortunately. One other solution would be running the Spring container in the same compose file. Otherwise, it'd be easier to just run Kafka on the host and mange the networking that way

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did what you suggested, put the spring app image in the same docker-compose file and ran all together, even that way it didn't work, this is insane, it´s got be a way to make this work.

Comment: 1) KAFKA_LISTENERS needs to be set to 0.0.0.0:(port) 2) Edit your question to show any properties you've modified? 3) If it's still running on a separate machine, then the container wouldn't help in that case until you setup a network bridge externally from compose

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind your server's public ip in order to be able to access brokers remotely. However if you don't want to hardcode the ip, you can use .env file.

Do the following:

1. Create config.env file.
2. Add this line in config.env and add your host ip as below:

   DOCKER_HOST_IP=111.111.11.111
3. Update your docker-compose:

```html
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 
         INTERNAL://kafka:29092,
         EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 
         INTERNAL://kafka:29092,
         EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 
         INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,
         EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 12
    
  connect:
    image: cdc:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-1
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-1-config
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-1-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-1-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_OFFSET.STORAGE.REPLICATION.FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_CONFIG.STORAGE.REPLICATION.FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET.STORAGE.PARTITIONS: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS.STORAGE.REPLICATION.FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS.STORAGE.PARTITIONS: 1
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      
  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    networks: 
      - broker-kafka
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 19000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
      
networks: 
  broker-kafka:
    driver: bridge
```

It will bind to 127.0.0.1, if DOCKER_HOST_IP is not found.

4. Run the following command:

```html
sudo docker-compose -f path-to-docker-compose.yml --env-file path-to-config.env up -d --force-recreate
```