# Broker not available when I run spring boot application with kafka inside Docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to docker and I'm having a problem running a Kafka broker inside a Docker container.
I developed spring boot application with kafka,producer and consumer in the same application .
application running successfully without docker , but when I try to run it through docker container on my host machine give me this error:

```
 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I used spring boot 2.4.2 and kafka_2.7.0

Steps I followed:

1-I build docker image for spring boot application.

2-I create docker-compose.yml to run zookeeper and kafka services as following:

```
version: '3'
services:
zookeeper:
image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
ports:
  - "2181:2181"     
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
environment:
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 2000000
  KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic1:1:1"
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
```

3- Then I execute the docker-compose.yml:
docker-compose up -d

4- Finally I run spring boot app image:
docker run -p 8080:8080 spring-boot-app .

This is my client config(spring boot app): application.properties:

## Consumer configuration

```
  #spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

  spring.kafka.consumer.group-id==group_id

  spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

  spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= 
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

  spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

## Producer configuration

```
  #spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

  spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=   org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

  spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: Your broker is advertising 'localhost', which is the localhost of the container. On the other side, your client is trying to connect to 'localhost', which is the localhost of it's own container. In compose file you should advertise on 'kafka' (the name of the compose service' and put your client in the compose file and configured to access 'kafka' instead of 'localhost'.

Comment: I did the first part but How can I put my client (spring boot app) in compose file?

Comment: @MohammedMostafa I added an answer about this question please check below. Also try service names not localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that how you can add your app to compose file. Before run this file create your image. I added network to combine them in same network section.

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"     
    networks:
      - app-network
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 2000000
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic1:1:1"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - app-network
  app:
    image: spring-boot-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
        - kafka
    networks:
      - app-network

          
networks:
   app-network:
     driver: bridge
```

Comment: I did this by error still exist, Are there configuration at client side at spring-boot-app as zigarn mentioned ?

Comment: I have changed `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. Please check again. Also please share you conf on app for kafka

Comment: Ok, I shared my client config for kafka producer and consumer

Comment: Use kafka:9092 instead of localhost:9092 as bootstrap server.

Comment: Exception changed give me now: Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka

Comment: Do you use docker image of spring app like I mentioned in answer? Try not using `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. I have edited answer.

Comment: You can't use image and build/context together in compose

Comment: The problem I have now: I pulled kafka and zookeeper images and run them inside docker, when i run my application from eclipse it listen good to kafka but when i create image for the application and run it inside docker container can't listen to kafka!!!

Comment: Replace `KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` with `KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure kafka brokers for external connections (outside docker container).

Edit your advertised listeners as below:

```html
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 
         INTERNAL://kafka:19092,
         EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
```

[Follow](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) this article for more insights.

For configuring kafka cluster on remote server, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182243/access-kafka-in-remote-host-by-ip-address-running-with-docker-compose-and-spring/66260624#66260624).

I used the following yml and it's working for me:

```html
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"     
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 2000000
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "Topic1:1:1"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: Ok I did this but give me exception: Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka and if I changed it to localhost:9092 couldn't listen to it

Comment: @Mohammed Your app isn't running in a container or on the same network if you get that error

Comment: @MohammedMostafa I used the above yml and it worked for me. Try it.

Comment: @ManjeetSingh, before I try what is configuration at client side(spring-boot-app)??

Comment: @MohammedMostafa, for external connections to docker, use localhost:9092 as bootstrap server.

Comment: @MohammedMostafa, Also I see you have put double equals while assigning group id of the consumer. I'm not sure if that's a valid configuration.
I'm talking about this:

 spring.kafka.consumer.group-id==group_id